# Make two markers share the same labels and simultaneously keep the black edge of patch in legend

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-maps-markers, legend

How should I modify my following code to make two markers share the same labels and simultaneously keep the black edge of patch in legend? Here are code (I have plotted the bars twice to decouple the edge color and hatch color) and plotted picture. I want to make the markers as shown in the second picture.

```
import matplotlib
matplotlib.rcParams['pdf.fonttype'] = 42
matplotlib.rcParams['ps.fonttype'] = 42
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

x_lable = ['3', '4', '5', '6', '7']

width = 0.3

Data1 = [96, 99, 100, 100, 100]
Data2 = [94, 96, 95, 96, 95]
Data3 = [48, 43, 42, 42, 37]

data_3 = [2228, 2621, 3165, 3761, 3763]
data_4 = [3895, 5670, 7354, 8999, 10731]
data_5 = [4355, 6373, 8279, 10105, 12018]

xcoordinate = [1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
xcoordinate_1 = [xcoordinate[0] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 0 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 0 * width]
xcoordinate_2 = [xcoordinate[0] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 1 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 1 * width]
xcoordinate_3 = [xcoordinate[0] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 2 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 2 * width]
xcoordinate_4 = [xcoordinate[0] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 3 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 3 * width]
xcoordinate_5 = [xcoordinate[0] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[1] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[2] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[3] + 4 * width, xcoordinate[4] + 4 * width]

fig = plt.figure()

# plot ax1
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(111)

ax1.bar(xcoordinate_3, data_3, width=width, label='GGG', color='none', edgecolor='orange', hatch='\\\\\\')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_4, data_4, width=width, label='SSS', color='none', edgecolor='blue', hatch='---')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_5, data_5, width=width, label='KKK', color='none', edgecolor='orangered', hatch='///')

ax1.set_ylabel('BBB')
ax1.set_xlabel('AAA')

ax1.bar(xcoordinate_3, data_3, width=width, label='GGG', color='none', edgecolor='black')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_4, data_4, width=width, label='SSS', color='none', edgecolor='black')
ax1.bar(xcoordinate_5, data_5, width=width, label='KKK', color='none', edgecolor='black')

handles1, labels1 = ax1.get_legend_handles_labels()
order = [0, 1, 2]
plt.legend([handles1[idx] + handles1[idx+3] for idx in order], [labels1[idx] for idx in order], loc=(2.5/10, 1.08), frameon=True, ncol=3, shadow=False, framealpha=1, labelspacing=1.05).get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')

# plot ax2
ax2 = ax1.twinx()

ax2.plot([i + 3 * width for i in xcoordinate], Data3, label='GGG', color='orange', linestyle='-', marker='p')
ax2.plot([i + 3 * width for i in xcoordinate], Data2, label='SSS', color='orangered', linestyle='-', marker='s')
ax2.plot([i + 3 * width for i in xcoordinate], Data1, label='KKK', color='limegreen', linestyle='-', marker='^')

ax2.set_ylabel('CCC')
plt.xticks([i + 3 * width for i in xcoordinate], x_lable)

handles2, labels2 = ax2.get_legend_handles_labels()
order = [0, 1, 2]
plt.legend([handles2[idx] for idx in order], [labels2[idx] for idx in order],  loc=(2.5/10, 1.005),  frameon=True, ncol=3, shadow=False, framealpha=1, labelspacing=1.05).get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')

plt.show()
```

Plotted picture:

[image: fig1]

What I want:

[image: fig2]

I want to keep the black edges of patches when two makers share the same label.

Comment: I'd start by [looking at the demos](https://matplotlib.org/stable/gallery/text_labels_and_annotations/legend_demo.html)

Comment: @ramzeek
Thanks for your reminding.  I have tried similar methods like in demos, but always get errors like: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'create_artists'.  I'm new to Matplotlib and not familiar with ‘handler’, especially I have plotted bars  twice  and do not know how deal with the handlers in this case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seemingly, we cannot simply group handles arbitrarily using the [HandlerTuple class](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/legend_handler_api.html#matplotlib.legend_handler.HandlerTuple) (or I am not clever enough). However, when more entries exist as defined by `ndivide`, the keys start from position 1 again, so we can write:

```
....
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerTuple
...
order = [0, 1, 2]
plt.legend([(handles1[idx], handles2[idx], handles1[idx+3]) for idx in order], [labels1[idx] for idx in order], handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=2)}, loc=(0.1, 1.04), frameon=True, ncol=3, shadow=False, framealpha=1, labelspacing=1.01, handlelength=5).get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')

....
```

to group 3 keys into 2 positions for each legend entry. This gives the following output:
[image]

I also increased the handle length with ...surprise... `handlelength=5` because otherwise, we would not see much of the hatch pattern.

Answer (score 1):

The third example in the official guide is what you want. To combine each handler, set them up in tuple form. If you don't want each handler to be stacked, you can add a configuration.

```
from matplotlib.legend_handler import HandlerLineCollection, HandlerTuple

#plt.legend([handles1[idx] + handles1[+3] for idx in order], [labels1[idx] for idx in order], loc=(2.5/10, 1.08), frameon=True, ncol=3, shadow=False, framealpha=1, labelspacing=1.05).get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')

plt.legend([(handles1[idx],handles2[idx]) for idx in order], [labels2[idx] for idx in order],  loc=(2.5/10, 1.005),  frameon=True, ncol=3, shadow=False, framealpha=1, labelspacing=1.05,handler_map={tuple: HandlerTuple(ndivide=None)}).get_frame().set_edgecolor('black')
```

[image]

Comment: Please update your code as the answer will be to introduce a handler tuple [add], disable the first legend setting [disable], and modify the second legend setting [modify].

Comment: Thanks for your answer. This method is nice, but I want to keep the black edge of patches (like in the first picture) in the legend.  I have tried to modify the code based on the examples in the tutorial before, but I can't make two markers share the same label and simultaneously keep the black edge.